# Custom theme in Material 2 returns: Argument `$map` of `map-get($map, $key)` must be a map

Tags: sass, angular-material2

I'm having a lot of difficulty implementing a custom theme for Angular 2 Material. I've been following the guides at:

- https://material.angular.io/guide/theming
- https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2017/05/23/custom-themes-with-angular-material.html

and have generated custom palettes for my colors. For example my "primary" color:

```
$dz-primary: (
    50 : #e8ebee,
    100 : #c6cdd4,
    200 : #a0acb7,
    300 : #7a8a9a,
    400 : #5e7184,
    500 : #41586e,
    600 : #3b5066,
    700 : #32475b,
    800 : #2a3d51,
    900 : #1c2d3f,
    A100 : #82baff,
    A200 : #4f9eff,
    A400 : #1c83ff,
    A700 : #0275ff,
    contrast: (
        50 : #000000,
        100 : #000000,
        200 : #000000,
        300 : #000000,
        400 : #ffffff,
        500 : #ffffff,
        600 : #ffffff,
        700 : #ffffff,
        800 : #ffffff,
        900 : #ffffff,
        A100 : #000000,
        A200 : #000000,
        A400 : #ffffff,
        A700 : #ffffff,
    )
);
```

When I attempt to create the custom theme:

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
@include mat-core();

@import './theme/dz-primary';
@import './theme/dz-accent';

$dz-theme-primary: mat-pallete($dz-primary);
$dz-theme-accent: mat-pallete($dz-accent);
$dz-theme: mat-light-theme($dz-theme-primary, $dz-theme-accent);

@include angular-material-theme($dz-theme);
```

The compiler always returns:

> Argument `$map` of `map-get($map, $key)` must be a map
>
> Backtrace:
>           node_modules/@angular/material/_theming.scss:1118, in function `map-get`
>           node_modules/@angular/material/_theming.scss:1118, in function `mat-color`
>           node_modules/@angular/material/_theming.scss:1530, in mixin `mat-option-theme`
>           node_modules/@angular/material/_theming.scss:3854, in mixin `mat-core-theme`
>           node_modules/@angular/material/_theming.scss:3920, in mixin `angular-material-theme`
>           stdin:11
>         in C:\Users\Brandon\work\angular-apps\dz-ui\node_modules\@angular\material_theming.scss
>   (line 1118, column 11)

This seems to be an issue with the `mat-color()` function not accepting the palette, but I can't seem to find what's wrong.

I have also tried using built-in colors from Material as referenced in the tutorials, but I receive the same error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like you spelt `mat-palette` as `mat-pallete`.

```scss
$dz-theme-primary: mat-palette($dz-primary); // <- Here
$dz-theme-accent: mat-palette($dz-accent); // <- Here
$dz-theme: mat-light-theme($dz-theme-primary, $dz-theme-accent);
```

Comment: Oh. My. God. Thank you. I now hang my head in shame.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are missing second argument in mat-pallete (value of color).

```
$dz-theme-primary: mat-pallete($dz-primary,100);
```

Comment: I've wasted quite a bit of time getting this going... I think I'll just switch back to Bootstrap and call it a day. I'd still like to know why this fails though.

Comment: Actually, it's optional to specify a second argument.